# How make java applets to run ALWAYS?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, java

Every time I meet java applet on some site, I have a problems running it. Either I have outdated JRE or `application is blocked` message appears.

I want to make browser/JRE NEVER check java updates, because they are issued nearly every day. I am not developing nuclear missiles, so I need no so high security.

Also I need browser/JRE NEVER block applets, or permit me to run them by force.

How to put some option somewhere to do so?

**UPDATE**

Is there any principal difference between Java runtime and other runtimes like Flash? Why nobody has problems running flash applets like Youtube page while JRE applets always cause problems?

Comment: In which version of which browser?  The mechanism for blocking Java has continually changed.

Comment: I wish to remove this mechanism. I don't understand why I can always run flash applets and never can run java applets. I see no principal difference between runtimes.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to state which browser, version, or OS?  Regarding the differences between Java and Flash, Java can run "privileged applets" which essentially give complete access to the computer.  Java also has a far worse history of vulnerabilities than Flash.

Comment: You can't use Java anymore in Firefox 52+.  However, Java runs in Waterfox 56 after you click "allow and remember".

Answer (score 5):

For security reasons, the following is highly **not** recommended.

For Firefox 29, type `about:config` in the address bar, click "I'll be careful, I promise!", and then change each of the following:

1. extensions.blocklist.enabled to `false`
2. plugin.state.java to `2`

---

For Java Update, click Start, type `regedit` and press enter.  Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and delete "SunJavaUpdateSched"